# Как разделить строки в списке по двум разным условиям?

Tags: python, разделение-строк

Есть список событий:

```
list = [
'2022-10-12 11:40:1',
'2022-10-12 11:41:2',
'2022-10-12 11:42:3',
'2022-10-12 11:43:2',
'2022-10-12 11:44:5',
]
```

Как разделить каждую строку в списке на дату (`2022-10-12 11:40`) и кол-во событий (`хххх-хх-хх уу:уу:1(2/3/5`)?

Answer (score 3):

воспользуйтесь [str.rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
res = [x.rsplit(":", 1) for x in data]
```

результат:

```
In [17]: res
Out[17]:
[['2022-10-12 11:40', '1'],
 ['2022-10-12 11:41', '2'],
 ['2022-10-12 11:42', '3'],
 ['2022-10-12 11:43', '2'],
 ['2022-10-12 11:44', '5']]
```

PS не называйте переменные зарезервированными словами, такими как `list`, `dict`, `set`, etc. Иначе вы не сможете потом ими воспользоваться.